# Naming AngularJS ngModel

Tags: angularjs

i have a question. Can you use "-" in the name of models

$scope['general-text'] = "haha";

ng-model="general-text"

this currently doesn't work. any suggestion?

Comment: use an underscore , general_text ,what's  the big deal with it?

Comment: because this are my data ids.

"general-text" : {"font-size" : 12}

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in an object on the scope.

```
$scope.data = {
  'general-text': 'haha'
};

ng-model="data['general-text']"
```